# Weird file behavior with git and screen

Tags: git, filesystems, screen

I recognized on a system I support following behavior. The scripts of the user are python scripts with pytorch as deep-learning cluster. The script is only partially written by the user. The Maintainer of the script is friendly said not very talented.

The following steps describes based on my knowledge and what the user told me:

1. The user switches to feature branch
2. The user starts `screen -S feature`
3. The user runs the time consuming script with many dependencies
4. The user detaches screen
5. The user starts `screen -S main`
6. The user switches to main branch
7. The user detaches screen
8. The User switches to feature branch
9. The user starts a few small changes on feature branch, but does not commit
10. The user waits for his scripts to finish
11. The user and I recognize that (still being in feature branch), that git has changes to files which were changed between main and feature. Those changes are the content of the main branch.

I also tested this scenario again to reproduce the behavior with no success. The script is running fine and don't change any file, not matter if launched directly or with a single screen.

What may have created the changes? I know this is not a lot of deep information about the environment, but I only support indirectly but I am happy for any idea. If the described behavior should never happened with the described steps. I tend to some weird backup/or-other-routines I don't maintain (based on the information that the drive where the git repo is located is a shared drive in the company).

Comment: Don't really understand what you are trying to do with the screen _but_ if your assumption is that because you are using it then git will _automagically_ deal with the working tree as if it had become a separate working tree, then that won't fly. You have a single working tree, each command that you run, regardless of session, will affect it.... there's more.

Comment: Then I think there is a problem with your assumptions about how git behaves with **uncommitted changes**. As long as a change is **not committed**, it does not belong to  a branch. If you modify 2 files, and then run `git switch`, git will carry over those 2 modified files the way they are to the branch you are trying to switch to (there are some checks that are run to allow this.. the modified files _have to_ be excatly the same between HEAD and where you want to go to to allow this to go through... if that is not the case, git will reject the switch... unless you force).

Comment: I try to explain what the attempt with screen is. Since the script can run for multiple days, the attempt was to run the script in parallel with two different version/branches. I agree for a statesave approach myself would use multiple worktrees, but my user insisted that this is to complicated for him/her. At the end we clone to different folders (don't ask me why worktrees are to complicated). The thing is my user worked in the past on the code which is running on screen with no Issues. From my perspective it seems the script works fine inside RAM after started.

Comment: About how git handles uncommited changes I am aware. The changes on which the scripts are running are already commited. The changes happend after the script finished.

Comment: It is not clear (at least to me) that you are using separate working trees... it just says that you switch between different screens and you say you switch between branches.... one could easily assume that it is a single working tree, right?

Comment: yes the behavior happened in a single working tree

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254474/discussion-between-makanu-and-eftshift0).

Comment: "*…the script works fine inside RAM after started…*" Inside RAM yes. But every time it needs data from files it takes them from **the current** working tree that could be different from the original working tree because another GIt process changed the tree. To run long-running scripts (`screen` or not) you need **stable (unchanged) working tree** for every long-running process. You need a **separate working tree** that nobody touches for every long-running process.

Comment: @phd Thanks that is what I was assuming but my user blamed `git` was doing this. I am still blindfolded why suddenly the state of the master is present as uncommited changes in feature branch, but this might stay an miracle caused by catastrophic codebase.

Comment: Either something outside of Git is changing your files, or it isn't. If the person claims it isn't, then remove all non-Git steps and see if it's repeatable. So, run only steps 1,6,8,9 and describe the issue. If you still see the issue, it will be much easier for us to help you explain what's happening from a Git point of view. (Which is probably something like uncommitted changes following you around...)

Comment: Wild guess- my previous comment won't be able to reproduce the problem. I think step 8 happened but some files couldn't be rewritten from their `main` versions because they were locked.

Comment: Oh, I just saw this, "the drive where the git repo is located is a shared drive in the company". That right there is very likely the source of your problem.

Comment: I don't think the lock is the reason in this process, because I am unable to reproduce the behavior with a single script. My wild guess (with me trying hardly to ignore the fact that the drive is shared) is the file, which is getting changed in step 9, is not the entry point instead gets imported. This could maybe generate some file trouble if some "lazy" loading is going to happen.